# Python extend dict value to list

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm trying to extend a dict value into a list in python 2.6    When i run the extend i'm not getting all dictionary values into the list. What am i missing?

```
def cld_compile(ru,to_file,cld):
    a = list()
    p = subprocess.Popen(ru, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    a = p.stdout.readlines()
    p.wait()
    if (p.returncode != 0):
        os.remove(to_file)
        clderr = dict()
        clderr["filename"] = cld
        clderr["errors"] = a[1]
    return clderr




def main():
    clderrors = list()
    <removed lines>
    cldterr = cld_compile(ru,to_file,cld)
    clderrors.extend(cldterr)
```

Return value of cldterr:

```
print cldterr
{'errors': 'fail 0[file.so: undefined symbol: Device_Assign]: library file.so\r\n', 'filename': '/users/home/ili/a.pdr'}
```

When i attempt to extend cldterr to the list clderrors i only get:

```
print clderrors
['errors', 'filename']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dict.__iter__` runs through all the KEYS of the dictionary without giving the values, so for something like:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
for element in d:
    print(element)
# "a"
# "b"
# "c"
```

That's why `list.extend` is only giving you the keys `"errors"` and `"filename"`. What would you LIKE it to give you, is the better question? I'm not even sure how that should be expected to work -- maybe a tuple of `(key,value)`? To do that, access `dict.items()` which will give you a `dict_items` object that yields `(key,value)` each iteration:

To use the same example:

```
for element in d.items():
    print(element)
# ("a",1)
# ("b",2)
# ("c",3)
```

Or in your case:

```
for key,value in cldterr.items():
    clderrors.append((key,value))

# or if you want future programmers to yell at you:
# [clderrors.append(key,value) for key,value in cldterr.items()]
# don't use list comps for their side effects! :)
```

Or simply:

```
clderrors.extend(cldterr.items())
```

Answer (score 5):

It it because `.extend()` expects a sequence, you want to use `append()` which expects an object.

For example

```
>>> l = list()
>>> d = dict('a':1, 'b':2}
>>> l.extend(d)
['a', 'b']

>>> l2 = list()
>>> l2.append(d)
[{'a':1, 'b':2}]
```

In Python when you iterate over a dictionary you get it's keys as a sequence, hence when using `extends()` only the dictionary keys are added to the list - as Python is asking for the same iterator we get when iterating over the dictionary in a `for` loop.

```
>>> for k in d:
        print k
a
b
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. it is expected, when you access dictionary by it's name, it would iterate over keys only. If you want dictionary values to be in list, you can do:

```
errList={'errors': 'fail 0[file.so: undefined symbol: Device_Assign]: library file.so\r\n', 'filename': '/users/home/ili/a.pdr'}
l= [(i +" "+ d[i]) for i in errList]
print l
```

Otherwise, you can access dictionary as list of tuples:

```
print errList.items()
```